# select row that is - 24 hours to go

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my DB I have a column called dato_tid (Datatype = date)

right now I have 2 post

1 where the date is 2018-07-18
2 where the date is 2018-07-20

I need to select the post, that has less then 24 hours to go

```
SELECT * FROM `udflyt` WHERE dato_tid > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day)
```

this line will select both posts

```
SELECT * FROM `udflyt` WHERE dato_tid > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -24 HOUR)
```

and so will this, I did try to change the > to < but the same.

```
SELECT * FROM `udflyt` WHERE dato_tid > (now() - interval 1 day )
```

this line will also get both posts

So what do I need to do, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, 24 hours to go means you should ADD a day, not subtract a day.

```
SELECT *
FROM `udflyt` 
WHERE dato_tid <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +1 day);
```

Will provide only the record with date '2018-07-18' (which is what you are looking for, I believe.

The below shows the values used for comparison for both doing addition and subtraction.

```
SELECT *, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +1 day), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day)
FROM `udflyt` 
WHERE dato_tid <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +1 day);
```